# VSCode error Command 'Live Server: Open with Live Server' resulted in an error (command 'extension.liveServer.goOnline' not found)

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Live server(5.6.1) did not shows in bottom right, then I used shift+command+p start live server.

Then I got this error  :
[image]

I have already tried delete local file and reinstall extensions, downgrade extensions and also reinstall VSCode.

Comment: okay that's weird. most vscode extension on my MAC failed ( vscode's html snippets, live serve), but they works perfectly on my Windows device...